# get POST data from a json callback in php

Tags: php, json

I am using an API that sends a callback using json POST requests to a page that I set.

Example of the callback:

```
{
"order": {
"id": "5RTQNACF",
"created_at": "2012-12-09T21:23:41-08:00",
"status": "completed",
"total_btc": {
  "cents": 100000000,
  "currency_iso": "BTC"
},

"custom": "order1234",
}
```

I need to know how I can take each of these parameters and have them set as php variables.

Comment: They'll be in `$_POST`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/json_decode) to take this string and get an array:

```
$array = json_decode($jsonString, true);
```

If you really want these as individual php variables, use [`extract`](https://www.php.net/extract):

```
extract($array); // now you have a local $order variable
echo $order['custom']; // etc...

extract($order); // now you have local variables $id, $status, etc
echo $id;
```

Example: http://3v4l.org/dqBjT

Keep in mind that `extract` could potentially overwrite other local variables, it's not generally considered good practice. I would recommend accessing the data you need in the `$array`.

**Update:** It sounds like you're struggling to access the posting JSON string in the first place. There are two possibilities:

1. If the data is being sent as a normal POST key/value pair, you can do `print_r($_POST)` on your page, and you should see where the json string is at.
2. It's possible that it is being sent as raw POST data and not key/value pairs. In which case you need to look at `file_get_contents("php://input");`. Try echoing that out. If you find your JSON string, then just set `$jsonString = file_get_contents("php://input");` and proceed with the `json_decode` next.

Comment: `extract` is discouraged, as it may overwrite local variables. `json_decode` and access the result element as arrays/nested arrays.

Comment: @aularon Totally agree. Which is why I said "If you really want..." It's better to access the array, yet I wanted to answer his question.

Comment: The json string is posted right to my call back page. So I would be unable to set $jsonString. Could I retrieve the parameters and set variables the same way form data can be parsed?

eg. $order = $_POST["order"];

Or am I way off track here?

Comment: You need to `json_decode` the string. How can you access the string to being with? `$_POST['something']`?

Comment: Way off then? My confusion is in "$array = json_decode($jsonString, true);" with "$array" being the json code itself. How can I set the "$array" variable if json is posted to page?

Comment: @Chris'Pig'Hill you haven't told us _how_ the json is posted to the page. Certainly you know at least how to spit out the post json? Where is it? What POST variable is it in???

Comment: I have never used json before. The API documentation states "Callbacks are always POST requests in JSON format to a callback url that you set." - The full documentation is here: https://coinbase.com/docs/merchant_tools/callbacks

Comment: @Chris'Pig'Hill I updated my answer, see the latter part. You need to debug your `$_POST` or the raw POST data `file_get_contents("php://input");` and see how the json string is being submitted to you. That's something only you can figure out. Once you find the json string, you can then decode and access the data.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
I echoed the json string and got back the correct data jumbled up with multiple "&quot"'s When I try to decode it using json_decode I get "200 1234567890"

Comment: @Chris'Pig'Hill You may need to do some other cleanup then, it sounds like you don't have valid json. Look at `urldecode` possibly. If you have trouble, post a new question. Taking the raw data and decoding to  a proper json string is really a different question/problem than what you original asked here.