# Decode json in php and create variables

Tags: php, json

I a trying to decode a json callback.

The json code is posted to callback.php - Here is an example of the json:

```
{
"order": {
"id": "5RTQNACF",
"created_at": "2012-12-09T21:23:41-08:00",
"status": "completed",
"total_btc": {
  "cents": 100000000,
  "currency_iso": "BTC"
},
"total_native": {
  "cents": 1253,
  "currency_iso": "USD"
},
"custom": "order1234",
"receive_address": "1NhwPYPgoPwr5hynRAsto5ZgEcw1LzM3My",
"button": {
  "type": "buy_now",
  "name": "Alpaca Socks",
  "description": "The ultimate in lightweight footwear",
  "id": "5d37a3b61914d6d0ad15b5135d80c19f"
},
"transaction": {
  "id": "514f18b7a5ea3d630a00000f",
  "hash": "4a5e1e4baab89f3a32518a88c31bc87f618f76673e2cc77ab2127b7afdeda33b",
  "confirmations": 0
},
"customer": {
  "email": "coinbase@example.com",
  "shipping_address": [
    "John Smith",
    "123 Main St.",
    "Springfield, OR 97477",
    "United States"
  ]
}
}
}
```

I can echo the json and get the following response:

```
    {&quot;order&quot;&quot;id&quot;:null,&quot;created_at&quot;:null,&quot;status&quot;:&quot;completed&quot;,&quot;total_btc&quot;:{&quot;cents&quot;:100000000,&quot;currency_iso&quot;:&quot;BTC&quot;},&quot;total_native&quot;:{&quot;cents&quot;:83433,&quot;currency_iso&quot;:&quot;USD&quot;},&quot;custom&quot;:&quot;123456789&quot;,&quot;receive_address&quot;:&quot;1A2qsxGHo9KjtWBTnAopTwUiBQf2w6yRNr&quot;,&quot;button&quot;:{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;buy_now&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Test Item&quot;,&quot;description&quot;:null,&quot;id&quot;:null},&quot;transaction&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;52d064b59eeb59985e00002c&quot;,&quot;hash&quot;:&quot;4a5e1e4baab89f3a32518a88c31bc87f618f76673e2cc77ab2127b7afdeda33b&quot;,&quot;confirmations&quot;:0}}}
```

However if I try to decode the json using the following:

```
$array = json_decode($jsonString, true);
echo $array;
```

I get the following response: "200 Array"

I want to be able turn each json parameter in to a php variable.

Comment: Don't `echo` the array `var_dump()` or `print_r()` it if you want to see string output for it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [get POST data from a json callback in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21052500/get-post-data-from-a-json-callback-in-php)

Comment: And that 200 isn't generated by the posted code, but I'm guessing somewhere else higher in the script you have echoed the result of an HTTP request and got a 200 response code.

Comment: If unsure how to work with arrays, try http://array.include-once.org/

Answer (score 2):

You can access the variables within `$array`, for example by doing:

```
echo $array['custom']; // prints out "order1234"
```

You don't want to extract the variables directly into the local lexical scope of your program as that would create security concerns. Just use the data as indicated in the snippet above.